# Show and hide image when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show an image when a thumbnail of it was clicked.

Here is my code as of now:

```js
$('.theme-preview').click(function() {

  console.log("fired");
  var previewPopup = $(this).children('.popup-preview');
  previewPopup.fadeIn("slow");

  previewPopup
    .css("position", "fixed")
    .css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - ($(this).children('.popup-preview').outerHeight() / 2))
    .css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - ($(this).children('.popup-preview').outerWidth() / 2));


  return false;

});

$('html').click(function() {
    $('.popup-preview').hide();
      return false;
 });
```

```css
.popup-preview {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.col-md-6 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-6.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-6.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-4.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-4.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-3.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-3.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-5.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-5.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The images are showing when click on any of the thumbnails. And it will hide if click outside of it.

What I want to add is:

- When I clicked a parent class (e.g. thumbnail #1) and shows the larger image, I want to hide the large image when I clicked again the parent class (e.g. thumbnail #1). As well as to other thumbnails.
- Then when I clicked the thumbnail #1 and shows the larger image, and click the thumbnail #2, the large image of thumbnail #1 will hide and the larger image of thumbnail #2 will show. The same as well to other thumbnails.

Note: When a large image was clicked(itself), it should not be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- On click, check if thumbnail to be shown is visible/
- If yes, hide it.
- If not, then hide any other thumbnail and show current thumbnail.

```js
$('.theme-preview').click(function() {

  var previewPopup = $(this).children('.popup-preview');
  if (previewPopup.is(":visible"))
    previewPopup.fadeOut("slow");
  else {
    $('.popup-preview:visible').fadeOut();
    previewPopup.fadeIn("slow");

    previewPopup
      .css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": ($(window).height() / 2) - (previewPopup.outerHeight() / 2),
        "left": ($(window).width() / 2) - (previewPopup.outerWidth() / 2)
      })
  }
  return false;
});

$('html').click(function() {
  $('.popup-preview').hide();
  return false;
});

$('.popup-preview').on("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

```css
.popup-preview {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.col-md-6 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-6.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-6.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-4.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-4.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-3.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-3.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-5.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-5.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if the popup is visible , if yes hide it if a user clicks on its thumbnail.If no , hide any popup that is open.And if a popup is visible and user clicks on other popup , still close any popup that is visible and show the corresponding popup.

```js
$('.theme-preview').click(function() {

  if($(this).children('.popup-preview').is(':visible')){
    $(this).children('.popup-preview').hide();
  }
  else{
    $('.popup-preview').hide();
  var previewPopup = $(this).children('.popup-preview');
  previewPopup.fadeIn();
   previewPopup
    .css("position", "fixed")
    .css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - ($(this).children('.popup-preview').outerHeight() / 2))
    .css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - ($(this).children('.popup-preview').outerWidth() / 2));
  }
  
 


  return false;

});

$('html').click(function() {
    $('.popup-preview').hide();
      return false;
 });
```

```css
.popup-preview {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.col-md-6 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-6.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-6.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-4.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-4.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-3.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-3.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="theme-preview"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-140-80-5.jpg">
      <div class="popup-preview">
        <div class="title">THEME 1-1</div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-240-180-5.jpg" width="100%">
        <div class="preview-btn">
          <a href="#"> <span>Preview</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add explanation. You are reading for readers and not just OP

Comment: Too close with @Rajesh answer. But his answer and explanation is more clearer.

Comment: @c.k no problem brother, I'm not here for any competition or race , just for help.